Replicating Esri's raster snapping using rasterio or GDAL
I have a legacy reference/snap raster (created using Esri ArcMap/Pro) and as part of my workflow I need to reproject multiple raster layers or rasterize polygon layers using rasterio or GDAL.
I wrote some code and got pretty close, but I can't replicate Esri's implementation of snapping. I am experiencing the following issues:

Cannot replicate the pixel origin e.g.,
Esri snap pixel origin for rasterized polygon 1704045.0000000004656613,2055194.9999999981373549
Rasterio transformation 1704045.0000000000000000,2055184.9999999981373549
Same dimensions: X: 3260 Y: 5133

The numbers themselves are incredibly small and I am happy with it, but the resulting layers have some pixels that are slightly off e.g., (orange layers is Esri snapped and gray is rasterio snapped -- the offset pixel is 30m wide and 20m height). I was expecting a consistent 30x30 offset.
Is there a way to replicate this snapping process or my attempt is the best I can do. The offsets are fine as long as they are consistent that is something I will test further. My biggest issue is having misalignment of pixels across multiple datasets.

Here's my code for a rasterizing some polygons and using the affine transformation from the reference/snap grid.
import rasterio 
from rasterio.mask import mask 
from rasterio.features import rasterize, shapes
from shapely.geometry import shape
import geopandas as gpd

snap_raster = '/.../Phase6_Snap.tif'
input_parquet = '/.../aoi.parquet'
output_raster = '/.../snap_test.tif'

gdf = gpd.read_parquet(input_parquet)

# create snap raster
with rasterio.open(snap_raster, 'r') as source:
    meta = source.meta.copy()
    old_transform = source.transform
    masked_snap, snap_transform = mask(source, shapes=gdf.geometry.to_list(), crop=True)

geoms = ((geom, int(value)) for geom, value in zip(gdf['geometry'], gdf['GEOID']))

height, width = masked_snap[0].shape

nodata = 0

rasterized = rasterize(
    geoms, 
    out_shape=(height, width), 
    fill=nodata,
    transform=snap_transform, 
    all_touched=False
)

meta.update(
    height=height,
    width=width,
    transform=snap_transform,
    nodata=nodata,
    compress='lzw'
)

with rasterio.open(output_raster, 'w', **meta) as sink:
    sink.write(rasterized, indexes=1)


The older Grid code required pixelX and pixel_Y to be the same ("cellsize"). I question whether it's necessary to reproduce that limitation.

I did ensure that both snap and resulting raster had same resolution/cellsize. Do you have any more thoughts about the workflow or the approach? I feel like I've hit a wall with this. Any insight is appreciated.

Thanks, @Vince. You were right, the issue was with pixel size transformations. I've answered my own question.

After further exploration, in order for, the above code to work the snap raster and the output raster should have same resolution. Earlier, I was using 10x10 (m) snap raster to create a 30x30 (m) output, and trying to replicate the affine transformation process in rasterio. However, it was much simpler, and faster, to create a new resampled 30x30 (m) snap raster in Esri desktop using the original 10x10 raster and then use it as reference raster moving forward with rasterio without complicated affine transformations. This fixed the issue.
